Flask-Socketio: Messages are not received by EC2 instance with an open IP address
The EC2 instance has a public IP address that I can use to initially connect to the server and have it return a webpage. I was able to do this by combining nginx and gunicorn after watching this video. For privacy, I'll just call it IPx or xx.xx.xx.xx. When I try and send a message to the server, I get the error the following error on the front-end:
WebSocket connection to 'ws://xx.xx.xx.xx/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=w0x8pR_PvOUyGyKSAAAA' failed:

I don't get the message on the server side
Right now, the EC2 has completely open inbound rules, so all incoming traffic could be accepted from any IP address (not a good idea, but I was desperate)
I have run similar code before and it would work on LAN, which is what makes this problem annoying.
Flask Backend

from improve_llm import LLM
from langchain_core.messages import AIMessage, HumanMessage

print("hello world")

llm = LLM()
chat_history = []
#chat_history.extend(HumanMessage(content=""))
#print(llm.ask(inp="who are the four partners in a Unified Command?", chat_history=chat_history) )


from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send
import json

print("Setting Up Web Server")

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")
chat_histories = {}

@socketio.on('connect')
def test_connect():
    print("User Connected! " + request.sid)
    chat_histories[request.sid] = []

@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(message):
    print("Recieved Message: " + message + " from SID == " + request.sid)
    ai_msg = llm.ask(message, chat_history)
    send(ai_msg)
    chat_histories[request.sid].extend(
        [
            HumanMessage(content=message), ai_msg
        ]
    )


@app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    print("app routed")
    return render_template("gpt-clone.html")
    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=80, allow_unsafe_werkzeug=True)

HTML Front End

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.7.5/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-luMnTJZ7oEchNDZAtQhgjomP1eZefnl82ruTH/3Oj/Yu5qYtwL7+dVRccACS/Snp1lFXq188XFipHKYE75IaQQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

    <title>ChatGPT-like GUI</title>
    <style>
        body {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: #f4f4f4;
        }
        .chat-container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            width: 400px;
            height: 600px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 10px;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: white;
        }
        .chat-header {
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #4caf50;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 18px;
        }
        .chat-messages {
            flex: 1;
            padding: 10px;
            overflow-y: auto;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
        }
        .message {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            white-space: pre-wrap;
        }
        .message.user {
            background-color: #e1ffc7;
            align-self: flex-end;
        }
        .message.bot {
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            align-self: flex-start;
        }
        .chat-input {
            display: flex;
            padding: 10px;
            border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
            background-color: #f4f4f4;
        }
        .chat-input input {
            flex: 1;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        .chat-input button {
            padding: 10px 15px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: #4caf50;
            color: white;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .chat-input button:hover {
            background-color: #45a049;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="chat-container">
        <div class="chat-header">Chatbot</div>
        <div class="chat-messages" id="chatMessages">
            <div class="message bot">Hello! How can I help you today?</div>
        </div>
        <div class="chat-input">
            <input type="text" id="userInput" placeholder="Type a message...">
            <button id="sendButton">Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
        var socket = io.connect("http://xx.xx.xx.xx/")
        console.log('Connected to the server');
        socket.on("message", function(data) {
            const userInput = document.getElementById('userInput');
            const chatMessages = document.getElementById('chatMessages');
            const messageText = userInput.value.trim(); // holds user input

            const botMessage = document.createElement('div');
            botMessage.classList.add('message', 'bot');
            botMessage.textContent = data;
            chatMessages.appendChild(botMessage);
            chatMessages.scrollTop = chatMessages.scrollHeight;
        });

        $(sendButton).on("click", function() {

            const userInput = document.getElementById('userInput');
            const chatMessages = document.getElementById('chatMessages');
            const messageText = userInput.value.trim(); // holds user input

            if (messageText !== '') {
                socket.send( messageText );
                console.log('sent to the server');
                const userMessage = document.createElement('div');
                userMessage.classList.add('message', 'user');
                userMessage.textContent = messageText;
                chatMessages.appendChild(userMessage);

                userInput.value = '';
                chatMessages.scrollTop = chatMessages.scrollHeight;



            }

        });
    });
        document.getElementById('userInput').addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
            if (event.key === 'Enter') {
                document.getElementById('sendButton').click();
                event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default action (form submission)
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

The main finding is that inbound rules don't matter at this point in time. I wonder if I would need to configure nginx differently to solve the issue, but I have no idea how I could go about fixing that. I've changed the port between 2000, 8000, and 80, so I doubt that's the issue either
EDIT: ADDING NGINX CONFIG
All I did was
point to the server variable
which basically pointed to the local IP

You haven't shared the complete error message in the client. You also ask about nginx but have not shared your configuration. The server log will also have details about these connection errors so that should be in your question as well.
